# How to properly compile C code for arduino with clang. (Timeout issues)

Tags: makefile, arduino, clang, avr, arduino-uno

I am trying to compile some simple bare metal C code for the atmega328p. I am uploading with arduino web uploader https://github.com/dbuezas/arduino-web-uploader/tree/master

Here is the c code

```
// This blinks an led
int main() {
        *((volatile unsigned char*)0x24) = 0xFF;
        while (1) {
                *((volatile unsigned char*)0x25) = 0x00;
                for (unsigned int i1 = 0;i1 < 65535;i1++)
                for (unsigned int i2 = 0;i2 < 65535;i2++)
                for (unsigned int i3 = 0;i3 < 65535;i3++)
                for (unsigned int i4 = 0;i4 < 65535;i4++)
                        asm volatile("nop");
                *((volatile unsigned char*)0x25) = 0xFF;
                for (unsigned int i1 = 0;i1 < 65535;i1++)
                for (unsigned int i2 = 0;i2 < 65535;i2++)
                for (unsigned int i3 = 0;i3 < 65535;i3++)
                for (unsigned int i4 = 0;i4 < 65535;i4++)
                        asm volatile("nop");
        }
}
```

The problem is I get the error `Error: Sending 6400004620: receiveData timeout after 400ms`
I have tested it out with some sample .hex files and it seems to work but whenever I compile myself I get his error. And so it must be an error with my Makefile

```
# The microcontroller
MCU := atmega328p
# The clock speed in Hz.
CLOCK := 16000000

CC  := clang
LLC := llc
MC  := llvm-mc

CFLAGS := -O -nostdlib -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -flto --target=avr -mmcu=$(MCU) -DF_CPU=$(CLOCK) -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR

LLCFLAGS := -march=avr -mcpu=$(MCU)

MCFLAGS := -arch=avr -mcpu=$(MCU)

C_SOURCES := $(shell find -name "*.c")

GENERATED_FILES :=

# if there are C sources, use them, otherwise search for IR files
ifneq "$(strip $(C_SOURCES))" ""
IR_FILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.ll,$(C_SOURCES))
GENERATED_FILES += $(IR_FILES)
else
IR_FILES := $(shell find -name "*.ll")
endif

# if there are IR files, use them, otherwise search of asm files
ifneq "$(strip $(IR_FILES))" ""
ASM_FILES := $(patsubst %.ll,%.s,$(IR_FILES))
GENERATED_FILES += $(ASM_FILES)
else
ASM_FILES := $(shell find -name "*.s")
endif

# if there are asm files, use them, otherwise search for obj files
# NOTE: we do not handle object files right now because the asm parser has a few bugs
ifneq "$(strip $(ASM_FILES))" ""
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.s,%.o,$(ASM_FILES))
GENERATED_FILES += $(OBJ_FILES)
else
#OBJ_FILES := $(shell find -name "*.o")
endif

all: $(IR_FILES) $(ASM_FILES) $(OBJ_FILES) main.hex

rebuild: clean all

clean:
        rm -rf $(GENERATED_FILES)

%.ll: %.c
        $(CC) -c -S -emit-llvm $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.s: %.ll
        $(LLC) -filetype=asm $(LLCFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.s
        $(MC) -filetype=obj $(MCFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.hex: $(OBJ_FILES)
        llvm-objcopy -O ihex $< $@ -B avr
```

It produces a main.hex but the upload dosen't seem to function here is the .hex file by the way

```
:100000008FEF84B920E030E015B8F901AF01F901B4
:10001000BF01F901D90100001196AF3FB80701F403
:100020003196EF3FF80701F4FB013196EF3FF807F7
:1000300001F4FA013196EF3FF80701F485B9F901AF
:10004000AF01F901BF01F901D90100001196AF3FDD
:10005000B80701F43196EF3FF80701F4FB01319640
:10006000EF3FF80701F4FA013196EF3FF80701F48A
:0200700000C0CE
:00000001FF
```

What have I done wrong in the makefile?

Comment: Still have to do some more testing but I think I figured it out. I needed :060400000895F894FFCFFF before the end of text line in the hex file. Avr is not fully supported on llvm so I didn't expect it to be bug free but this was a surprisingly simple fix.

Comment: I don't understand fully why replacing :0200700000C0CE with :060400000895F894FFCFFF fixes the upload but I think it has something to do with exiting programming mode.

Comment: Nevermind it seems to only work that executable

Comment: I have deciphered a bit but I don't have any idea why the there is relative jump to a non existent address at the end
```:060400000895F894FFCFFF

// Jumping to 0x0000000 when stack is empty
0895
1001 0101 0000 1000
ret

// Clearing all interrupts
F894
1001 0100 1111 1000
cli

// Relative jump to who knows where
FFCF
1100 1111 1111 1111
rjmp ??? ??? ???```